# Highcharts exporting once again

Tags: php, excel, export, highcharts, xls

So i have chart like this http://jsfiddle.net/9uDmV/

I wrote function to get export link to xls

```
 {
  text: 'Download as xls',
  onclick: function() {
  location.href="getXLS.php?param1=param&param2=para2";}
   }
```

But i don't want to use GET as export because it's redirect me to page getXLS.
I want to make it like other functions (for example export to png, i click on it and download window appears)

I think I should use AJAX for this but don't know how exacly use it....

for saveing data to xls I will use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ but first I need to POST that data without reloading the page to getXLS.

count on you, guys!

and sorry for bad english ;-)

index_ajax.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'inbound datas'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'last ten days'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['2012-08-01', '2012-08-02', '2012-08-03', '2012-08-04', '2012-08-05', '2012-08-06', '2012-08-07', '2012-08-08', '2012-08-09', '2012-08-10', '2012-08-11', '2012-08-12']
            }],
            exporting: {
            buttons: {
                exportButton: {
                    menuItems: [{},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}, /* leave standard buttons */
                    {
                        text: 'Download as xls',
                        onclick: function() {
                                    $.get("ajax.php", { param1: "param1", param2: "param2" } );
                                }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
            yAxis: [{ 
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                alternateGridColor: null,
                plotBands: [{ // High wind
                    from: 90,
                    to: 100,
                    color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                    label: {
                        text: 'AR to get',
                        style: {
                            color: '#606060'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                title: {
                    text: 'AR'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },{ 
                min: 0,
                max: 8000,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'Inbound',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value;
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var unit = {
                        'AR': '% ',
                        '1': '1',
                        '2': '2',
                        '3': '3'
                    }[this.series.name];

                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' '+ unit;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -100,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                yAxis: 1,
                name: '1',
                data: [2000, 1000, 3000, 2000, 1000]
            }, {
                yAxis: 1,
                name: '2',
                data: [4000, 7000, 4000, 6000, 5000]
            }, {
                name: '3',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#F7801F',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [90, 80, 70, 90, 85],    
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
   echo 'a prompt windows should apper';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correct, you want to force a download instead of redirection? If so, add these headers to the top of `getXLS.php`

```
<?php
  // We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;'); // This should work for IE & Opera
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");    // This should work for the rest       
// It will be called dataAsExcel.xls
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dataAsExcel.xls"');
?>
```

This will indicate the browser that you are sending a file of type excel, and the browser will hence prompt the user with a `save as` dialog box.

More about headers in php @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: yes and no, i'm sending variables from chart and then getXLS.php generates XLS file and shows window with save as dialog box.
simplier: if you click on "Download as PNG" in chart it will prompt windows with download a PNG file. Now i want to make option to save XLS and also prompt windows should apper

Comment: I think I lost you, have you included the above headers to your getXLS.php ?
If you want to use ajax you can do this in the onclick event handler $.get("getXLS.php", { param1: "param1", param2: "param2" } );

Comment: I've try it but i think thath i'm doing somethings wrong :/
In getXLS.php i've got:
`<?php
   echo 'a prompt windows should apper';
?>`

and file with charts changed to
`{
                        text: 'Download as xls',
                        onclick: function() {
         $.get("ajax.php", { param1: "param1", param2: "param2" } );
        }
                    }`
Here is all files
http://www.speedyshare.com/4Ypd7/charts.zip

I will be grateful for your help

Comment: Sorry don't have access to file sharing sites from work, can you update the question to add new contents of the php file too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15064/discussion-between-jugal-thakkar-and-breq)

Answer (score 0):

OK, how to do that:

Firtst, make function

```
function postajax(datas)
{
$.post('PHPExcel/export/ajax.php', datas, function(retData) {
  $("body").append("<iframe src='PHPExcel/export/ajax.php' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
}); 
}
```

now create button to download xls file

```
buttons: {
            exportButton: {
                menuItems: [{},
                {},
                {},
                {}, /* leave standard buttons */
                {
                    text: 'Download as xls',
                    onclick: function() {
                        postajax('My vaariable') 
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

And that's all, now download library from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
and you'r done!

Big thanks to @Jugal Thakkar for his help and patient!